# add the html file in android application to open in browser?

Tags: android

I imported .html file into android application (assets/www/.html). Now i tried to access that data to my app as webview.loadUrl("file://android_assets/www/new4.html");. But while running it in eclipse, Emulator is showing "webpage not available ". Any help is appreciatable.

Comment: If you recently added `new4.html` file in `Assets` then you must uninstall your app and again install it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

WebView webView = // ...

webView.loadUrl("file:///myPath/myFile.html");
In an Android application, files can be read from 3 types of locations:

Internal storage: Each app has its own, file names are relative to this location. URL takes form file:///myFolder/myFile.html

External storage: Needs permission and may not always be available. Get the root folder by calling Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). So, construct the URL using: String url = "file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "myFolder/myFile.html"

Assets: Stored in the apk. Read-only access. URL takes form file:///android_asset/myFolder/myFile.html

Comment: hello sir, i have did same as you told but its not working. i want to display my html page on button  click in web view.the web view page open but when i click on subscribe buuton on this then  Emulator is showing "webpage not available ". Any help is appreciatable.